# jquery ui autocomplete without filter

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I need to show user all autocomplete choices, no matter what text he already wrote in the field? Maybe i need some other plugin?

```
$('#addressSearch').autocomplete("search", "");
```

That doesn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two scenarios:

1. You're using a local data source. This is easy to accomplish in that case:

   ```
   var src = ['JavaScript', 'C++', 'C#', 'Java', 'COBOL'];
   $("#auto").autocomplete({
       source: function (request, response) {
           response(src);
       }
   });
   ```
2. You're using a remote data source.

   ```
   $("#auto").autocomplete({
       source: function (request, response) {
           // Make AJAX call, but don't filter the results on the server.
           $.get("/foo", function (results) {
               response(results);
           });
       }
   });
   ```

Either way you need to pass a function to the `source` argument and avoid filtering the results.

Here's an example with a local data source: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/e9t5Y/

Answer (score 0):

You can set the minLength option to 0, then it should work.