# jQuery-UI Autocomplete is "stuck" on the initial value; does not respond to arrow keys as expected

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete, usability

I have `<input>` elements that use autocomplete and they also have initial values.
The problem is that my users expect to click on the input and use the up/down arrow keys to change those values -- just like autocomplete allows if there is no initial value (and also just like a `<select>` behaves).

**HTML:**

```
<label>
    Input with 4 possible values:
    <input type="text" value="green" id="tstInp">
</label>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#tstInp").autocomplete ( {
    delay: 0,
    minLength: 0,
    source: ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow"]
} )
```

**jsFiddle:**

**[jsfiddle.net/v0b4ymch/](http://jsfiddle.net/v0b4ymch/)**

**To duplicate the problem**:

1. Load the fiddle and focus the input.
2. Now use the up and down arrow keys to try and change the value.
3. You will see only the initial value and a dropdown with only the initial value.
4. Now erase the value from the input and repeat step 2.
5. You will be able to cycle through all possible values, just like with a `<select>`. And, you will be able to filter values by typing letters.

Ideally in step 3, not only would the arrow keys cycle through the possible values, but they would *start* at the initially entered value (`green` in this example).  EG:

> [image: Desired initial behavior]

The only difference between the expected behavior and what autocomplete currently does is that immediately after the input is focused, the *initial* up/down arrow keys should show all possible values -- ideally with the initial value already focused in the dropdown menu.

How can I get autocomplete to respond to the up/down arrows as expected?

---

I'm using jQuery 2.1.0 and jQuery-UI 1.11.1.

Comment: OK, what happens if users enters `bl` on step 4? Should it display all values or just `blue`?

Comment: @SalmanA, just `blue`.  (And that part correctly works, once the input has been cleared.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one possible solution:

- Show all values when dropdown is opened using the down-arrow key
- Fallback to default behavior otherwise

```javascript
var source = ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow"],
    showall;
$("#autocomplete1").autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    search: function(event, ui) {
        showall = event.which === 40;
    },
    source: function(request, response) {
        response(showall ? source : $.ui.autocomplete.filter(source, request.term));
    }
});
```

[**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/v0b4ymch/8/)

---

Original answer:

It is possible to open the dropdown and show all values manually (e.g. on click of a button) by (i) setting [`minLength: 0`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-minLength) (ii) calling [`search`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-search) method and passing an empty string. You can ook this behavior in the focus event of the textbox or add a dedicated button for this purpose.

[**Old Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/v0b4ymch/4/)

Comment: Yeah.  Looks like I'll have to make a state machine on/for focus, search and keydown.  This is the answer if nothing better shows up in the next 24 hours. Thanks.

Comment: I had second thoughts. The dropdown opens on various events such as (i) when user is typing (ii) down-arrow is clicked. You could trap the latter event and override the search behavior to show _all_ values; use the default behavior otherwise.

Comment: Close. Works all but for one case (select, blur, focus, {oops}) (ETA: maybe not, I used up-arrow for test).  Any reason you downrevved the jQ and jQUI used?  Anyway, I need to sleep on this.

Comment: (i) you'll have to hit the down arrow (that is the how you activate an empty autocomplete) (ii) no particular reason; just that jsFiddle has these particular versions added in the Frameworks section.

Comment: Note that I chose this answer since it is currently the best solution, and my actual code will be categorically similar. (Plan to post that in the next day or two -- probably just append it to this answer).  But this answer does meet *all* requirements, so please don't edit the question to match the answer. ;)

Answer (score 2):

thats how it should behave like, when you put a value and if that value does not have match in the list, it will show nothing, if it has one or more matches then it will show those matched values.
I hope this 
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v0b4ymch/1/) will help you understand.

```
source: ["red", "green", "greenish", "blue", "yellow"]
```

Comment: On your fiddle: (1) erase the input, (2) use the arrow keys to scroll down to `green`. Notice that the input has `green` and all values are still listed (no filtering yet).  ***That's*** how the users we tested expected this control to behave (it's part of a combobox).  How can I do that?

Comment: sorry it became little confusing, when you erase the input and up/down arrow key shows options, Should there be filtering applied on up/down arrow key? Without even you select it?

Comment: Filtering should work as normal -- except at initial focus, it looks like.  Up down keys should scroll through available choices as filtered but only new (re)focus of the input, before any keypress, filtering should ignore the input value.

Comment: I guess this answer is right from a given perspective. Looks like I have to extend this control to make it user friendly?

Comment: why not use combobox then? I guess that is what you are looking for? Is it?

Comment: Yes, this is actually part of a combobox.  I looked for existing plugins but haven't found one I liked yet.  The bare-bones jQUI combobox looks okay so far but it has this usability issue too.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/v0b4ymch/2/

Pass a function for the source option and don't filter the results

```
var src = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow'];

$("#tstInp").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        response(src);
    }
});
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526354/jquery-ui-autocomplete-without-filter)

Comment: Thanks.  It does solve the initial arrow key issue, but it breaks the filtering.  With the input cleared, it still needs to act as a standard autocomplete.

Comment: This does give me an idea to try though.